# xpage creates save conflict on save/submit

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage that on submit of an edit to an existing document, a save conflict is created each time you click the submit button. I am the only one that has access to this application currently so I do know there are not any other users that be be saving also.

Comment: Do you save the document in several places when submitting?

Comment: Post your. Source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this when I attached a document data source to multiple custom controls that I used in that xpage. When the save document simple action was executed it resulted in save conflicts all the time.

Comment: Hi Oliver.  I don't follow your solution.  Did you remove the other custom controls?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. My solution simply was to move the datasource to the XPages insetad of the CC - OR - to not use the save simple action and define a datasource to be saved in the action properties. I tend to use both in the CC.

Comment: Thakns - I did not pick up from your answer that you had moved the datasource to the xpage out of the cc.  I will look at doing that.